# CHECK: Let $p$ be a prime number and let a $\in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $p\mid a^p+a(p-1)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a \in\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $p\mid a^p+a(p-1)!$.

$p\mid a^p+a(p-1)!$ if $p\mid a^p$ and $p\mid a(p-1)!$.

$\gcd(p,(p-1)!)=1$ $\implies$ $ p \nmid (p-1)!$ so $p\mid a$ $\implies$ $p\mid a^p$

Hence, $p\mid a^p+a(p-1)!$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. It's Fermat meets Wilson.

Comment: It is not correct. Certainly if $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ divides your sum. But you are asked to show that $p$ divides your sum for **all** $a$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your assumption about if $p | A+B$, then $p|A$ and $p|B$ is incorrect. For example, with $p=7$ we have $7|(4+3)$ but it doesn't divide $4$ and $3$.

You need to use two results: Fermat's little theorem and Wilson's theorem.
Fermat says: For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$.

Wilson says: For prime $p$, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Both are standard results. Using them we get
\begin{align*}
a^p+a(p-1)! & \equiv a+a(-1) \pmod{p}\\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{p}.
\end{align*}